# How to fix : lexical error in string/character literal at character ' " ' in ghci

Tags: haskell

This type given by the exercise is used for logical propositions.What I'm trying to do is define an instance for Show to this particular type.

This here is my code:

```
data Prop = Var String | Not Prop | And Prop Prop | Or Prop Prop

p1::Prop
p1 = Not (Or (And (Not( Var "A")) (Var "B")) (Var "C"))

instance (Show Prop) where
    Var s = show s
    Not s = "-" ++ show s
    And s d = show s ++ "/\ " ++ show d
    Or s d = show s ++ "\/" ++ show d
```

For example, the p1 defined above , after show defined is supposed to  appear as :
"-((-A /\ B) / C)"

I'm getting this error:

```
T1516.hs:48:33: error:
lexical error in string/character literal at character '"'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `"/\ "` is parsed thus:

- `"`: a string literal starts here.
- `/`: a forward-slash character
- `\`: the start of an [escape sequence](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/lexemes.html#sect2.6). Backslashes in string literals are *not* interpreted as an actual backslash character that should appear in the string you're trying to define, but as a control character introducing such an escape sequence. But then...
- : a space. Spaces can't be part of escape sequences, but there is one way in which this can be done nevertheless: if you're trying to escape a line break in a long string literal. for instance (line breaks highlighted)

  ```
  foo :: String↲
  foo = " bla bla \      ↲
        \ bum blum blam \↲
        \ gum gao wo"↲
  ```

  is a legal string literal. The backslashes extend it into the next line, namely until the the leading backslash there, and it doesn't matter that there are spaces between the trailing backslash and the line end. What you have in your code is not ok though:
- `"` is illegal at this point, because you've started an escape sequence that can only be a newline, but this is not a newline.

What you want instead is a literal backslash. You can achieve that in a string literal with the escape sequence `\\`

```
  show (And s d) = show s ++ "/\\ " ++ show d
  show (Or s d) = show s ++ "\\/" ++ show d
```

If you have lots of backslashes in string literals, you may consider using [raw string literals](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/raw-strings-qq) which don't have any escaping.

A nicer alternative is to just use proper Unicode symbols:

```
  show (And s d) = show s ++ "∧" ++ show d
  show (Or s d) = show s ++ "∨" ++ show d
```

these don't need to be escaped in any way.

---

BTW this `Show` instance won't really work properly, namely it won't have proper grouping / precedence. For instance, `And (Or a b) (Or c d)` will be rendered as `a∨b∧c∨d`, which is logically different. To get proper parenthisation, you need to define `showsPrec` rather than the simple `show`:

```
instance (Show Prop) where
  showsPrec p (Var s) = showsPrec p s
  showsPrec p (Not e) = showParen (p>=7)
       $ ("¬"++) . showsPrec 7 e
  showsPrec p (And s d) = showParen (p>=3)
       $ showsPrec 3 s ++ "∧" ++ showsPrec 3 d
  showsPrec p (Or s d) = showParen (p>=2)
       $ showsPrec 2 s ++ "∨" ++ showsPrec 2 d
```

Also note that it's considered good etiquette that `Show` instances should spit out valid Haskell code. For the `∧` and `∨` operators that's easy enough to achieve:

```
infixr 3 ∧
(∧) = And
infixr 2 ∨
(∨) = Or
```

but Haskell doesn't have support for prefix operators like `¬`. You *could* actually get prefix `-` by implementing a `Num` instance, but *please don't*, this would be very confusing. So, you should better change the `Not` clause to just yield `"Not"`:

```
  showsPrec p (Not e) = showParen (p>=10)
       $ ("Not "++) . showsPrec 10 e
```

Answer (score 3):

Write `"\\/"` instead of `"\/"`. Symbols starting with `\` are called escape sequences, and there is no `\/` sequence. The `\\` sequence just outputs `\`, which is exactly what you need.

Note that this isn't specific to Haskell language.

Comment: The same goes for `"/\"`, which should be `"/\\"` instead.